# Vmware Player doesnt start ubuntu

Tags: vmware

```
(vmware-installer.py:4095): Gtk-WARNING **: Impossible de trouver le moteur de thème dans module_path : « murrine »

(vmware-installer.py:4095): Gtk-WARNING **: Impossible de trouver le moteur de thème dans module_path : « murrine »

(vmware-installer.py:4095): Gtk-WARNING **: Impossible de trouver le moteur de thème dans module_path : « murrine »

(vmware-installer.py:4095): Gtk-WARNING **: Impossible de trouver le moteur de thème dans module_path : « murrine »

(vmware-installer.py:4095): Gtk-WARNING **: Impossible de trouver le moteur de thème dans module_path : « murrine »

(vmware-installer.py:4095): Gtk-WARNING **: Impossible de trouver le moteur de thème dans module_path : « murrine »

(vmware-installer.py:4095): Gtk-WARNING **: Impossible de trouver le moteur de thème dans module_path : « murrine »

(vmware-installer.py:4095): Gtk-WARNING **: Impossible de trouver le moteur de thème dans module_path : « murrine »
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module": libcanberra-gtk-module.so: Ne peut ouvrir le fichier d'objet partagé: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you are doing. What OS are you using as a host? What happens exactly when you try to run the Ubuntu guest? Is it an Ubuntu guest? Have you installed it on the virtual machine? The messages you show are irrelevant, they're just GTK warnings. Oh, and next time, please run the command like this so the messages are in English: `LC_ALL=C vmware`